# Java Stream: is there a way to iterate taking two elements a time instead of one?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Let's say we have this stream

```
Stream.of("a", "b", "err1", "c", "d", "err2", "e", "f", "g", "h", "err3", "i", "j");
```

and I want to save in a map the couples of adjacent strings in which the first one starts with "err".

What I thought of is something like this

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();

Stream.of("a", "b", "err1", "c", "d", "err2", "e", "f", "g", "h", "err3", "i", "j")
.reduce((acc, next) -> {
    if (acc.startsWith("err"))
        map.put(acc,next);
    if (next.startsWith("err"))
        return next;
    else
        return "";
});
```

But I'm not totally satisfied with it for two main reasons

1. I'm "misusing" `reduce` function. In Stream API every function has its clear, well defined purpose: `max` is supposed to calcuate max value, `filter` is supposed to filter based on a condition, `reduce` is supposed to produce an incrementally accumulated value and so on.
2. Doing that prevents me from using Streams powerful mechanisms: what if I wanted to limit my search to the first two results?

Here I used `reduce` because (as far as I know) it's the only function that lets you compare couple of values that you can, somehow, lead back to something similar to "current value" and "next value" concepts.

Is there a more straightforward way? Something that allows you to iterate the stream considering more than one value for each iteration?

## EDIT

What I'm thinking about is some mechanism that, given the current element, allows you to define a "window of elements" to consider, for each iteration.

Something like

```
<R> Stream<R> mapMoreThanOne(
    int elementsBeforeCurrent,
    int elementsAfterCurrent,
    Function<List<? super T>, ? extends R> mapper);
```

instead of

```
<R> Stream<R> map(Function<? super T, ? extends R> mapper);
```

That would be a powerful "upgrade" to current API.

## EDIT2

I appreciate the effort of people proposing their solution, but the issue is not the algorithm per se. There are different ways to achieve my goal by putting together streams, indexes, temp variables to store previous values... but I was wondering if there was some method in Stream API that was designed for the task of dealing with elements other than the current without breaking the "stream paradigm". Something like this

```
List<String> list =
        Stream.of("a", "b", "err1", "c", "d", "err2", "e", "f", "g", "h", "err3", "i", "j")
        .filterFunctionImWonderingIfExist(/*filters couples of elements*/)
        .limit(2)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Given the answers, I think there's no "clear and quick" solution, unless using StreamEx library

Comment: Looks like you need a Collector

Comment: I thought about that, but I couldn't find a (nice and clean) solution

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can build a custom [`Collector`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collector.html) for this task.

```
Map<String, String> map = 
    Stream.of("a", "b", "err1", "c", "d", "err2", "e", "f", "g", "h", "err3", "i", "j")
          .collect(MappingErrors.collector());
```

with:

```
private static final class MappingErrors {

    private Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();

    private String first, second;

    public void accept(String str) {
        first = second;
        second = str;
        if (first != null && first.startsWith("err")) {
            map.put(first, second);
        }
    }

    public MappingErrors combine(MappingErrors other) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Parallel Stream not supported");
    }

    public Map<String, String> finish() {
        return map;
    }

    public static Collector<String, ?, Map<String, String>> collector() {
        return Collector.of(MappingErrors::new, MappingErrors::accept, MappingErrors::combine, MappingErrors::finish);
    }

}
```

In this collector, two running elements are kept. Each time a `String` is accepted, they are updated and if the first starts with `"err"`, the two elements are added to a map.

---

Another solution is to use the [StreamEx](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex) library which provides a [`pairMap`](http://amaembo.github.io/streamex/javadoc/one/util/streamex/StreamEx.html#pairMap-java.util.function.BiFunction-) method that applies a given function to the every adjacent pair of elements of this stream. In the following code, the operation returns a String array consisting of the first and second element of the pair if the first element starts with `"err"`, `null` otherwise. `null` elements are then filtered out and the Stream is collected into a map.

```
Map<String, String> map = 
    StreamEx.of("a", "b", "err1", "c", "d", "err2", "e", "f", "g", "h", "err3", "i", "j")
            .pairMap((s1, s2) -> s1.startsWith("err") ? new String[] { s1, s2 } : null)
            .nonNull()
            .toMap(a -> a[0], a -> a[1]);

System.out.println(map);
```

Comment: So, well, there's not a more straightforward way. +1 for StreamEx library, very interesting project! `PairMap` perfectly addresses my needs

Comment: @LuigiCortese I don't think so no. That's unfortunate. Scala has a nice [`sliding`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.Seq@sliding%28size:Int,step:Int%29:Iterator[Repr]) method on Stream that would be appropriate here: it groups elements in fixed size blocks.

Comment: I've heard about that. IMHO that's a big, deep hole left there right in the middle. It could be much more synthetic and easly understandable

Comment: correct me if I'm wrong, your solution doesn't allow to limit your search to the first *n* couples, right?

Comment: @LuigiCortese With the `pairMap` solution, you could add a `.limit(2*n)` after the `.filter(Objects::nonNull)` so that it limits to n couples.

Comment: Clear, I was referring to custom collector solution. I need to take a close look at this StreamEx...

Comment: Also why `.limit(2*n)`? Seems that `.limit(n)` is what @LuigiCortese wants.

Answer (score 9):

You can write a custom collector, or use the much simpler approach of streaming over the list's indexes:

```
Map<String, String> result = IntStream.range(0, data.size() - 1)
        .filter(i -> data.get(i).startsWith("err"))
        .boxed()
        .collect(toMap(data::get, i -> data.get(i+1)));
```

This assumes that your data is in a random access friendly list or that you can temporarily dump it into one.

If you cannot randomly access the data or load it into a list or array for processing, you can always make a custom `pairing` collector so you can write

```
Map<String, String> result = data.stream()
        .collect(pairing(
                (a, b) -> a.startsWith("err"), 
                AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry::new,
                toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue)
        ));
```

Here's the source for the collector.  It's parallel-friendly and might come in handy in other situations:

```
public static <T, V, A, R> Collector<T, ?, R> pairing(BiPredicate<T, T> filter, BiFunction<T, T, V> map, Collector<? super V, A, R> downstream) {

    class Pairing {
        T left, right;
        A middle = downstream.supplier().get();
        boolean empty = true;

        void add(T t) {
            if (empty) {
                left = t;
                empty = false;
            } else if (filter.test(right, t)) {
                downstream.accumulator().accept(middle, map.apply(right, t));
            }
            right = t;
        }

        Pairing combine(Pairing other) {
            if (!other.empty) {
                this.add(other.left);
                this.middle = downstream.combiner().apply(this.middle, other.middle);
                this.right = other.right;
            }
            return this;
        }

        R finish() {
            return downstream.finisher().apply(middle);
        }
    }

    return Collector.of(Pairing::new, Pairing::add, Pairing::combine, Pairing::finish);
}
```

Comment: Well, in the original problem source stream is a log file, so you don't really have access to indexes.

Answer (score 7):

Things would be easier if your input is located in the random-access list. This way you can utilize good old `List.subList` method like this:

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("a", "b", "err1", "c", "d", "err2", "e", 
     "f", "g", "h", "err3", "i", "j");

Map<String, String> map = IntStream.range(0, list.size()-1)
    .mapToObj(i -> list.subList(i, i+2))
    .filter(l -> l.get(0).startsWith("err"))
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(l -> l.get(0), l -> l.get(1)));
```

The same thing could be done with already mentioned StreamEx library (written by me) in a little bit shorter manner:

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("a", "b", "err1", "c", "d", "err2", "e", 
     "f", "g", "h", "err3", "i", "j");

Map<String, String> map = StreamEx.ofSubLists(list, 2, 1)
    .mapToEntry(l -> l.get(0), l -> l.get(1))
    .filterKeys(key -> key.startsWith("err"))
    .toMap();
```

Though if you don't want third-party dependency, the poor Stream API solution looks also not very bad.

Comment: I like the idea behind StreamEx, I hope to come out with some interesting PR soon =)

Comment: @LuigiCortese, please note though that I not eagerly accept every single enhancement. Every enhancement has many pros and cons to evaluate. For example, I'll likely to reject any new feature which shows poor parallel performance. Probably it would be better to discuss your idea first in the [issue tracker](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex/issues)

Answer (score 2):

Other approach with `Collector.of` and `List<List<String>>` as structure to collect pairs.
First collect to `List<List<String>>`:

```java
List<List<String>> collect = Stream.of("a", "b", "err1", "c", "d", "err2", "e", "f", "g", "h", "err3", "i", "j")
        .collect(
                Collector.of(
                        LinkedList::new,
                        (a, b) -> {
                            if (b.startsWith("err"))
                                a.add(new ArrayList<>(List.of(b)));
                            else if (!a.isEmpty() && a.getLast().size() == 1)
                                a.getLast().add(b);
                        },
                        (a, b) -> { throw new UnsupportedOperationException(); }
                )
        );
```

Then it can be transform to map

```java
Map<String, String> toMap = collect.stream().filter(l -> l.size() == 2)
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                e -> e.get(0),
                e -> e.get(1))
        );
```

Or all in one with `Collectors.collectingAndThen`

```java
Map<String, String> toMap = Stream.of("a", "b", "err1", "c", "d", "err2", "e", "f", "g", "h", "err3", "i", "j")
        .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(
                Collector.of(
                        LinkedList<List<String>>::new,
                        (a, b) -> {
                            if (b.startsWith("err"))
                                a.add(new ArrayList<>(List.of(b)));
                            else if (!a.isEmpty() && a.getLast().size() == 1)
                                a.getLast().add(b);
                        },
                        (a, b) -> { throw new UnsupportedOperationException(); }
                ), (x) -> x.stream().filter(l -> l.size() == 2)
                        .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                                e -> e.get(0),
                                e -> e.get(1))
                        )
        ));
```

Answer (score -2):

Here's a simple one liner using an off-the-shelf collector:

```
Stream<String> stream = Stream.of("a", "b", "err1", "c", "d", "err2", "e", "f", "g", "h", "err3", "i", "j");

Map<String, String> map = Arrays.stream(stream
        .collect(Collectors.joining(",")).split(",(?=(([^,]*,){2})*[^,]*$)"))
    .filter(s -> s.startsWith("err"))
    .map(s -> s.split(","))
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(a -> a[0], a -> a[1]));
```

The "trick" here is to first join all terms together into a single String, then split it into Strings of pairs, eg `"a,b"`, `"err1,c"`, etc. Once you have a stream of pairs, processing is straightforward.

Comment: Bad idead. This is very error-prone. If there is a `,` in one of the input Strings it will do unexpected things. besides ... what is this crazy RegEx all about? :-)