# How to pass in Streams Prev element result to next one

Tags: java, functional-programming, java-8, java-stream

I have List of items where on each item I need to create some calculation. 
Each calculation is built by the preceding element.

So for example:

```
List<Object> Users=new ArrayList<>();
users.stream().filter(element->calculateSomething(<need-prev-element-input>).findFirst();
```

The calculateSomething will return true/false depends on the prev element calculation result in the stream

Any idea how can I do that?

Comment: you need a predicate

Comment: Mybe I can design it different to use streams?

Comment: @rayman:  No.  Almost certainly not.  Give up on using streams.  Streams are very good at certain kinds of operations and very bad at anything else.  What you need is something they are very bad at.

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ 웃 Пepeúpa ツ predicate how??

Comment: it seems you need to consume two elements at a time: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34086461/java-stream-is-there-a-way-to-iterate-taking-two-elements-a-time-instead-of-one

Comment: You are describing an attempted solution instead of your actual problem. There might be a stream solution, perhaps even a simple one, but we can’t tell you if you don’t describe your actual problem.

Comment: 5 years later but looking at his other comments what he really needed was a reduce

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Streams are *not* designed to be able to do any operation like this.  You *might* be able to hack something together to do that, but it'll be awful; you should go back to using normal loops instead.

Comment: what with foreach? also wont be possible? e.g users.foreach(item->....)

Comment: Not really.  You'd need an awkward holder object because lambdas can't access nonfinal variables.  Seriously.  Use a normal loop.

Comment: Yes, streams are designed to handle each item with no dependency to others.

Answer (score 5):

If you really want to use streams, stream over indexes:

```
IntStream.range(1, users.size())
        .filter(i -> calculateSomething(users.get(i-1) , users.get(i)))
        .map(users::get)
        .findFirst();
```

There are also a number of non-standard libraries that let you stream over pairs from a list.

Comment: it seems great. and the `calculateSomething` don't need the current element at all.

Comment: what if instead passing the last element in the stream to the current element I want to pass the result of the last calculation to the current element?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the Java 8 way of doing it:

```
<T extends User> Optional<T> findUserSomehow(List<T> users) {
  for (int idx = 1; idx < users.size(); ++idx) 
    if (calculateSomething(users.get(idx - 1)))
      return Optional.of(users.get(idx));
  return Optional.empty();
}
```

Comment: what if I dont need to object of prev element just a result from the prev iteration of the loop.. how would you modify that?