# Generics and streams: How to make this into a `StreamTuple::new` statement?

Tags: java, generics

I am working on a small library which emulates multi-value return values in Streams.  For this to work well, I would like to be able to use `StreamTuple::new` instead of `StreamTuple::create` or `id -> new StreamTuple<>(id, id)`.  I tried various modifications, but my generics-fu is not good enough to figure out how to change the source to allow this.

```
public class StreamTuple<L, R> {

    protected final L left;
    protected final R right;

    public StreamTuple(L left, R right) {
        this.left = left;
        this.right = right;
    }

    /**
     * Suitable for method::references.  Value is set to id.
     */

    public static <L> StreamTuple<L, L> create(L left) {
        return new StreamTuple<>(left, left);
    }
    ....
```

Calling code snippet:

```
    Map<String, String> m = Stream.of("1", "2", "3")
//          .map(StreamTuple::create)
            .map(id -> new StreamTuple<>(id, id))
            .collect(toMap(StreamTuple::left, StreamTuple::right));
```

Suggestions?  Or can't it be done?

---

EDIT:  I would like an additional constructor that only takes one argument and returns a StreamTuple where L and R is the same type. The current code does not reflect that because it was a while ago I couldn't make it work and I thought I replicated it.  I can only find out how to provide one of L / R and that leaves the other one open.  How to write a single argument constructor for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to do this with a constructor, because there's no way to specify that the argument is a subtype of both `L` and `R` (i.e. conjunction/intersection). The language has a construct for such a requirement, but an intersection between type variables is not allowed:

```
// not allowed (causes a compilation error)
//                 vvvvv
public <LR extends L & R> StreamTuple(LR val) {
    this.left = val;
    this.right = val;
}
```

That might work in a future version of Java, however.

You have to use a factory method or, I suppose, what tsolakp suggested. I think the factory makes more sense.

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered extending `StreamTuple` in order to define single argument constructor?

```
 Map<String, String> m = Stream.of("1", "2", "3")
.map( UnaryStreamTuple<String>::new )
.collect( Collectors.toMap(UnaryStreamTuple::left, UnaryStreamTuple::right) );

public class UnaryStreamTuple<T> extends StreamTuple<T, T> {

    public UnaryStreamTuple(T left) {
        super(left, left);
    }

    public UnaryStreamTuple(T left, T right) {
        super(left, right);
    }        
}
```

Comment: I was thinking of generalizing it.  I did not think of this.  Interesting.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen I dont see many other ways of having the same argument assigned to both L and R (which are different types) so this to me seems the smartest way to impose L=R and assign the same value to both w/o risk of runtime errors. I was also suggesting a similar approach, w/o extending the class.

Answer (score 1):

It can't be done since you're passing `id` twice. `StreamTuple::create` is the way to go.

Comment: You are right. The code does not reflect that what I really wanted to have was a single argument constructor that can implement both L and R.

Answer (score 1):

Stream's [`map` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#map-java.util.function.Function-) requires a `Function` that takes in exactly one parameter and returns something else.

However, what you are attempting to use is `StreamTuple::new`, and that takes in 2 parameters, e.g. a `BiFunction`, so that doesn't match.

I suppose you could use `flatMap` to have two copies of each stream element, then [write a custom `Collector`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34086461/java-stream-is-there-a-way-to-iterate-taking-two-elements-a-time-instead-of-one) to collect these items 2 at a time, but that sounds like a lot more work than referencing your `create` method, which already matches.

What will work best is what you've done -- a factory method that takes exactly one parameter and returns the desired `StreamTuple`.

Comment: I would like a constructor that only takes one argument and returns a StreamTuple where L and R is the same type.  The current code does not reflect that (because it is too long ago I did this)

Answer (score 1):

`StramTuple::new` will be translated differently based on the FunctionalInterface expected by the accepting method.

expecting [Function](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html) (T -> R) ==> ::new translates to `new StreamTuple(t)`

expecting  [BiFunction](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/BiFunction.html) (T,U -> R) ==> ::new translates to `new StreamTuple(t,u)`

expecting [Supplier](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Supplier.html) (() -> R) ==> ::new translates to `new StreamTuple()`

Since Stream#map is expecting a [Function](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html), this cannot translate to the 2-args constructor. So your `create` factory method seems a good way to go.

Having a 1-arg contructor (like the below) behaving like the `create` method is not possible since compiler will complain because R is not bound

```
public StreamTuple(L both) { //will fail compilation
    this.left = both;
    this.right = both;
}
```

**BUT** since you want a 1-arg constructor and its argument must be assignable to both R and L, then you have 2 options:
1) one extends the other (e.g. R is assignable to L)

```
public class StreamTuple<L, R extends L> {

    protected final L left;
    protected final R right;

    public StreamTuple(R both) {
        this.left = both;
        this.right = both;
    }
}
```

2) if R and L are not related, then you need Object with casts on getters:

```
public class StreamTuple<L, R> {

    protected final Object left, right;

    public StreamTuple(Object o) {
        this.left = this.right = o;
    }

    public <L> L getLeft() { return (L) left; }
    public <R> R getRight() { return (R) right; }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately that constructor definition wont even compile.

Comment: Tried making such a constructor.  Basically Java does not like it because R is not bound.

Comment: Thanks - updated answer (for the sake of truth). So this answer might still represent the best explanation, and @tsolakp's the best and most elegant solution (kudos).. to you Thor the hard choice :)

Comment: Thanks @PaoloC. But I personally think that static factory method is the best approach to take.

Comment: Me too, but that does not answer the question "How to write a single argument constructor for this" :)

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen am I closer with the latest option? Having a 1 arg constructor has nice implications: if that emerges in the generics declaration then it works

Comment: The generic case is that L and R are unrelated and we cannot make that assumption, unfortunately :-(

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen added last implementation for that

Comment: @PaoloC I appreciate your efforts but how will L and R get bound in the actual scenario?  The problem here is to tell the compiler how to bind both L and R to the same type.

Comment: In the last option you'll not be able to enforce them to be of the same type, but compiler will eventually bind getters to the same type and you'll be able to use your toMap() method and then assign to Map<T,T>. From a theoretical perspective, I think there is nothing in between this last solution (binding getters and using Object as value holder, since Object is the only common ancestor assignable from any type) and tsolakp's solution (extending the class to enforce T/T in the holder). That is, either you bind the value holders or you bind the getters with casting.

Comment: @PaoloC Casting is exactly what I want to avoid as it will involve more typing and be more brittle as it sidesteps generics entirely.  Admittedly this is a design corner case in generics, but I still want all the help the compiler can give me.

Comment: Out of curiosity, did you actually try the last code snippet?  How would L and R be bound?  What does the `.map(....new...)` look like?

Comment: Yes, here it is: `Map<String, String> m = Stream.of("1", "2", "3").map(StreamTuple::new).collect(toMap(StreamTuple::getLeft, StreamTuple::getRight));`