# Return new Array that adds up every 2 values?

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, return

I am trying to create a method that will take in an array and return a new array that adds every 2 values to create one new value and move on to the next 2 values. If I have an array of {5,8,4,2} I want that array to become {13,6}. So far in my code I have it set up to where it creates an array of {5,8,4,2} and makes it into {13, 12, 6, 0} However, I don't want it to add that way. So I was wondering how do I get my program to skip over the 2nd value after doing the first addition? Also, how do I get rid of that useless zero at the end?

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class reduceArray{
   public static int[] reduce(int[] currentArray){
   int[] newArray = new int[currentArray.length];

   for(int i = 0; i < currentArray.length -1; i++){


     newArray[i] = currentArray[i] + currentArray[i+1];


      }

     return newArray;

   }

   public static void main(String[] args){
       int[] arrayANew;
       int[] arrayA = {5,8,4,2};



       arrayANew= reduce(arrayA);



       System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arrayANew) );




    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you’d want to increment the index to skip every other element?

Comment: I originally had it so the for loop would add by 2 each time and that somewhat worked however, instead in the new array the next index would return only a zero. Example: array of {15, 20, 30, 1} would return as {35, 0, 50, 0, 31}

Comment: Similar question but focused on solutions using Java Streams: [*Java Stream: is there a way to iterate taking two elements a time instead of one?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34086461/642706)

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specifically address whether the current array is always even in length, but we can handle odd-length arrays without too much trouble:

```
public static int[] reduce(int[] currentArray) {
    int[] newArray = new int[(currentArray.length + 1) / 2];

    for(int i=0; i<currentArray.length; i++) {
        newArray[i/2] += currentArray[i];
    }

    return newArray;
}
```

Test:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(reduce(new int[] {5, 8, 4, 2})));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(reduce(new int[] {5, 8, 4, 2, 7})));
```

Output:

```
[13, 6]
[13, 6, 7]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just need to increment through the new array differently than the old one, as shown below.
(I also added changed it to be able to handle arrays of odd lengths and make newArray the right length)

```java
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
class Scratch{
    public static int[] reduce(int[] currentArray){
        int[] newArray = new int[(int) Math.ceil((float) currentArray.length / 2)];

        if (newArray.length % 2 != 0) newArray[newArray.length - 1] = currentArray[currentArray.length - 1];

        for(int i = 0, j = 0; i < currentArray.length -1; i+=2, j++){
            newArray[j] = currentArray[i] + currentArray[i+1];
        }

        return newArray;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        int[] arrayANew;
        int[] arrayA = {5,8,4,2};

        arrayANew= reduce(arrayA);

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arrayANew) );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to move the index you are accessing in `currentArray` over by two each time you go through your `for` loop:

```
public static int[] reduce(int[] currentArray) {
    int[] newArray = new int[currentArray.length / 2]; //needs to be half the length

    for(int i = 0; i < newArray.length; i++) { //use newArray's length since we are iterating over newArray
        newArray[i] = currentArray[2 * i] + currentArray[2 * i + 1]; //need to multiply indices by 2 to provide that "jumping" effect
    }

    return newArray;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] arrayANew;
    int[] arrayA = { 5, 8, 4, 2 };
    arrayANew = reduce(arrayA);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arrayANew));
}
```

Note that this assumes the array has an even number of elements.  If you need it to also work with arrays of odd length, use the following:

```
public static int[] reduce(int[] currentArray) {
    int[] newArray = new int[currentArray.length / 2 + ((currentArray.length & 1) == 1 ? 1 : 0)]; //needs to be half the length

    for(int i = 0; i < newArray.length; i++) { //use newArray's length since we are iterating over newArray
        newArray[i] = currentArray[2 * i] + (2 * i + 1 >= currentArray.length ? 0 : currentArray[2 * i + 1]); //need to multiply indices by 2 to provide that "jumping" effect
    }

    return newArray;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] arrayANew;
    int[] arrayA = { 5, 8, 4, 2 };
    arrayANew = reduce(arrayA);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arrayANew));
}
```

Comment: I have updated my answer to also include a solution that works for arrays with an odd number of elements, too.

Answer (score 0):

This will handle arrays of even or odd length.  If odd, the last element in the `result` array will be the last element in the `vals` array.

```
int[] vals = { 10, 2, 3, 10, 1, 2, 3, 6};
int[] result = new int[(vals.length +1) / 2];
for (int i = 0; i < vals.length; i += 2) {
    result[i / 2] = vals[i] + (i <vals.length-1 ? vals[i + 1] : 0);
}

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result));
```

prints

```
[12, 13, 3, 9]
```

Points to consider.

- The `results` array is sized to round up if need be.
- Whether to try and add the last value is controlled by a `ternary` operator