# Using stream API estimate difference between object properties

Tags: java

I have a class:

```
public class MyObject {
    
    private int a;
    private int b;

    public MyObject(int a, int b) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }

    public int getA() {
        return a;
    }

    public int getB() {
        return b;
    }

}
```

How can I identify using stream whether a collection has difference between varB of previous and varA of next object is greater than a specified value (200)?

It seems that reduce is similar to my need, but it expects as a result the object of type MyObject, and I need bool instead

```
var list = Arrays.asList(
    new MyObject(100, 200);
    new MyObject(300, 400);
    new MyObject(700, 800);
);

var result = list.stream().reduce((a, b) -> b.getA - a.getB > 200 ? true : false); // <-- !WRONG!
```

**EDIT**

Many thanks to all who responded, from my point the most suitable way is to create a custom collector:

```
public class MyCollector {

    private int count = 0;
    private static long refValue = 200;

    private MyObject right;

    public void accept(MyObject newValue) {
        var left = right;
        right = newValue;
        if (left == null) return;
        var diff = right.getA() - left.getB();
        if (diff > refValue) count++;
    }

    public MyCollector combine(MyCollector other) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Parallel Stream not supported");
    }

    public int finish() {
        return count;
    }

    public static Collector<MyObject, ?, Integer> collector(long v) {
        refValue = v;
        return Collector.of(MyCollector::new, MyCollector::accept, MyCollector::combine, MyCollector::finish);
    }

}
```

And the usage is:

```
var result = list.stream().collect(MyCollector.collector(200) != 0; // <- true because the stream has an difference (700 - 400) 300
```

Comment: Perhaps a custom collector might help? See examples of implementation here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34086461/java-stream-is-there-a-way-to-iterate-taking-two-elements-a-time-instead-of-one

Comment: @meridbt If I understood, you want to check if `next.a - prev.b > value` is true for all elements of your collection, if so result is `true`, else it is `false` ?

Comment: @Tom, yes, you got me absolutely right. If at least one difference is greater than 200, return true. In the sample above (300 - 200) not greater than 200. (700 - 400) greater than 200, so the final result must be true

Comment: @SusanMustafa, your suggestion looks suitable for my need, there is only one thing I doubt - if there is a way to pass a value to compare to custom collector?

Answer (score 1):

You want a `zip` operation where two or more streams are joined like a zipper.

If your have two lists `xs` and `ys` like

```
xs = [10, 5, 20, 7]
ys = [2, 8, 11, 12, 43]
```

A `zip` operation join pair by pair discarding elements of the longest one

```
zip(xs, ys) = [(10, 2), (5, 8), (20, 11), (7, 12)]
```

If you want to compare an element with its predecessor, you just have to remove the first one and zip

```
zip(xs, xs.skip(1)) = [(10, 5), (5, 20), (20, 7)]
```

In your specific case, *Java 8* does not have a `zip` operation but Guava have and you can write

```
Streams
        .zip(list.stream(), list.stream().skip(1), (a, b) -> b.getB() - a.getA())
        .forEach(delta -> System.out.printf("    %d%n", delta));
```

with output

```
300
500
```

since the `zip` result is a new stream, you can map and filter as you need

```
Streams
        .zip(list.stream(), list.stream().skip(1), Tuple2::new)
        .filter(tup -> tup._2.getB() - tup._1.getA() > 400)
        .forEach(tup -> System.out.printf("    A := %s, B := %s%n", tup._1, tup._2));
```

with output

```
A := MyObject(a=300, b=400), B := MyObject(a=700, b=800)
```

(Note: to use [Guava](https://github.com/google/guava) you can include

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
    <version>31.0.1-jre</version>
</dependency>
```